# Why is the *= operator not functioning the way I would expect it to?

Tags: c++, operators

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    //If a triangle has a perimeter of 9 units, how many iterations(each iteration is 4/3 as much) would it take to obtain a perimeter of 100 units? (or as close to 100 as you can get?)
    double p = 9; int it = 0;
    for(p; p < 100; p = p * 4/3){
        cout << p << endl;
        it++;
    }
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << it << endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

So for a math project I was doing, I had to figure out how many iterations it would take for a perimeter of 9 to reach 100 if you increase the perimeter 4/3x as much during each iteration. When I write the code like I do above, the output is fine, however if I change

```
for(p; p < 100; p = p * 4/3)
```

to

```
for(p; p < 100; p *= 4/3)
```

I get output that doesn't make sense. Am I misunderstanding the *= operator? Do I need parentheses somewhere?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's the order of operation. In `p = p * 4/3` the compiler is doing:

```
p = (p * 4)/3
```

However in `p *= 4/3`, the compiler is doing:

```
p = p * (4/3)
```

4/3 is 1 on the computer because of integer division, so the second example is basically multiplying by 1.

Instead of dividing by 3 (an integer), divide by 3.0 (a double) or 3.0f (a float). Then p *= 4/3.0 and p = p * 4/3.0 are the same.

Comment: When in doubt, add parenthesis!

Comment: Or get all fortrany and write `4./3` or `double(4)/3` or any of a variety of other incantation which will force the use of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Jonathon: Parentheses won't help here though, will they? `p *= (4/3)` is still wrong.

Comment: @TonyK, of course. I only said that because of the potential ambiguity in his working statement `p = p * 4/3`.  The OP's use of spacing is incredibly misleading, because as we know, this functions as `p = (p*4) / 3`

Comment: @Jason what would be the best way to ensure I am using float division in the future to avoid a problem like this?

Comment: C++ converts up to the most complex type. Instead of dividing by 3 (an integer), divide by 3.0 (a double) or 3.0f (a float). Then p *= 4/3.0 and p = p * 4/3.0 are the same.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, except that should be `p *= 4.0 / 3.0`